# Setting Shopping Cart Rules Makes Site VERY slow

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I am using Magento CE 1.8.1.0.
I set about 150 shopping cart rules.
I noticed that the rules validation process makes adding/updating/deleting a product VERY VERY slow. 
For example if I add a product to a cart that contains already 20 products it take 5-10 minutes.
Any idea how to optimize the rule validation process?

Thanks

Comment: My server spec is: 8 GB RAM, 4 CPU with SSD hard disk.

Comment: Could you show the rules you have set up? in addition how many skus do you have?